Connect button no function
I tried to run safe-wallet-web locally. Yarn starts it smoothly and the page responds on port 3000 as expected.
But both of the connect buttons ("top_bar"/"welcome_page") don't connect me to my wallet (Metamask)
I tried different browsers and the live site app.safe.global works fine with the same setups.
Running safe-wallet-web version 1.47.5, but also tried older ones.
Watching an existing safe account is working, so connecting to Mainnet seems to work.
I assume i am missing maybe any variable in the .env section. Would be nice is somebody here could get me a hint. Or do i need to install some missing packages on my Ubuntu 22.04LTS. There is no console output.
Thanks in advance
Sascha
